# How to put a condition in the select of linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select values from LINQ

but these values depend on another control in my windows form in C#

Here is my code

```
var lstInfo = grdBreakDown.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
    .Select(x => (tag: x.Cells["tag"].Value.ToString(), Scheme: x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString(), Value: x.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString()))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

lvwInfo.Items.AddRange( lstInfo
    .Select(x => new ListViewItem(new string[] { x.tag, x.Scheme, x.Value }))
    .ToArray()
);
```

This code works perfectly and displays all Schemes something like this

```
    Tag  Scheme  Value
    Red  Master  88
    Red  Master  14
    Red  Admin   39
    Red  Admin   31
    Blue Master  91
    Blue Master  10
    Blue Admin   54
    Blue Admin   04
```

But I want to make a few changes and only displays Schemes & Value when a checkbox in the windows form is ticked and if not ticked just display empty string

something like this

```
    .Select(x => (
        tag: x.Cells["tag"].Value.ToString(),
        Scheme:
            if(
                (!cbxMaster.checked &&  x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Master")
                ||
                (!cbxAdmin.checked &&  x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Admin"), "", x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString()
            ),
        Value:
            if((!cbxMaster.checked &&  x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Master")
                ||
                (!cbxAdmin.checked &&  x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Admin"), "", x.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString()
            )
    )
```

So if Master ticked an Admin is not ticked

output will be like this

```
    Tag  Scheme  Value
    Red  Master  88
    Red  Master  14
    Red     
    Blue Master  91
    Blue Master  10
    Blue
```

but this is not working.

how to do that with linq?

Comment: Your string literals are not correctly enquoted. I've corrected this for you.

Comment: Give to the database the work of the database

Comment: @LeandroBardelli the control is decided in the windows form, it is a front end issue

Comment: "but this is not working." - what error do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify what you have selected, you have to browse through the entire selection.

```
var lstInfo = grdBreakDown.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
                               .Select(x => (tag: x.Cells["tag"].Value.ToString(), Scheme: x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString(), Value: x.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString()))
                               .Distinct()
                               .ToList()
                               .foreach (elem=>{
                                     if(elem.Sheme.equals("Admin")){
                                         elem.Sheme="";
                                         elem.value="";}
                                });
```

Comment: Distinct is before the condition in your solution.
but distinct has to be after

Comment: For the complexity it better to be before. So the for each loop will not iterate elements for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a conditional operator for the value you are searching for?

```
.Where(x => x.Cells["Scheme"].Value.ToString() == ((checked) ? "Master" : "Admin") )
```

Checked could be a bollean value or whether the tickbox is ticked. I think this will work

Comment: This is where condition, it will remove all non matching criteria

Answer (score 0):

**Define the problem**

You could translate that to: Get the values of the `Admin` and/or `Master` rows if the corresponding `CheckBox` controls are checked. Otherwise, get their distinct tags.

Thus:

```cs
private void PopulateListView()
{
    // Local function...
    (string tag, string scheme, string value) GetItems(DataGridViewRow row) =>
        (chkAdmin.Checked && row.Cells["scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Admin") ||
        (chkMaster.Checked && row.Cells["scheme"].Value.ToString() == "Master")
        ? (
        row.Cells["tag"].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells["scheme"].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells["value"].Value.ToString())
        : (
        row.Cells["tag"].Value.ToString(),
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty);

    var lstInfo = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
        .Select(x => GetItems(x))
        .Distinct()
        .Select(x => new[] { x.tag, x.scheme, x.value });

    lvwInfo.Items.Clear();
    lvwInfo.Items.AddRange(lstInfo.Select(x => new ListViewItem(x)).ToArray());
}
```